# Why the (1)JDBC code works while the (2) does not?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

(1)

```
import java.sql.*;

public class jdbcDemo

{static Connection con=null;

    public static void main(String args[])
    { int id = 0;
    try
    { Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
      con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:login");

      Statement stat = con.createStatement();
      System.out.println("got connection");
      ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("Select max(UID) from mytable");
      while(rs.next())
      { id=rs.getInt(1);
      }
      id++;
      System.out.println(id);
      PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT into mytable(UID,Username,Password) values(?,?,?)");
      ps.setInt(1,id);
      ps.setString(2,"abhi");
      ps.setString(3,"bindra");


       ps.executeUpdate();





        }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

       e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
}
```

(2)

```
import java.sql.*;

public class jdbcDemo

{static Connection con=null;

    public static void main(String args[])
    { int id = 0;
    try
    { Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
      con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:login");

      Statement stat = con.createStatement();
      System.out.println("got connection");
      ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("Select max(UID) from mytable");
      while(rs.next())
      { id=rs.getInt(1);
      }
      id++;
      System.out.println(id);
      PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT into mytable(UID,Username,Password) values(?,?,?)");
      ps.setInt(1,id);
      ps.setString(2,"abhi");
      ps.setString(3,"bindra");


       ps.executeUpdate();
       String s1,s2;
       ResultSet rs1 = stat.executeQuery("Select  * from mytable where UID="+id+"");
        while(rs1.next())
        {
            s1=rs1.getString(2);
            s2=rs1.getString(3);
            System.out.print(s1+s2);
        }





        }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

       e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
}
```

**The part**

```
ResultSet rs1 = stat.executeQuery("Select  * from mytable where UID="+id+"");
    while(rs1.next())
    {
        s1=rs1.getString(2);
        s2=rs1.getString(3);
        System.out.print(s1+s2);
    }
```

why is the part so essential? why doesnt ps.executeUpdate() inserts the row into the table.?The record does not appear in the table without the part being inserted in (1).

Comment: If you use an IDE, then please figure out how it can reformat your source.

Comment: I don't see any difference in how you are inserting between part 1 and part 2. The select query after the execute should not make any difference. Jdbc connections by default has autoCommit set to true. So executeUpdate() should commit the data provided that you didn't get any exceptions.

Comment: @Thorbjorn :Am not using any IDE ..just textpad.

Comment: @CoolBeans :Exactly,i totally think it should not make any difference, but i have totally blanked out.i tried an UPDATE query in the prepared statement and executed it without part , it wasnt executing until i inserted'part' in it. seriously , something is wrong

Comment: Try doing doing a manual commit. `con.commit();`

Comment: Could this have something to do with it ?"PrepareStatement :This method is optimized for handling parametric SQL
     statements that benefit from precompilation. If the driver
     supports precompilation, the method prepareStatement will
     send the statement to the database for precompilation. Some
     drivers may not support precompilation. In this case,
     statement may not be sent to the database until the
     PreparedStatement object is executed. This has no 
     direct effect on users; however, it does affect
     which methods throw certain SQLException objects. "

Comment: Please People i need some help :(

Comment: There's so much wrong with the code that I don't know where to start answering. Here's at least a link which should put you in the right track: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html

Comment: For starters, you are not closing your connections or statements.  Please consider using jdbcTemplate from spring.  You should not be managing jdbc connections directly.  This is very difficult to get right unless you really understand what is going on.

Comment: well, that blog is very exhaustive. i will surely read it tomorrow. thankyou :) . Well @BalusC : what is so wrong with the code ? i know that id is autoNumber and it will generate itself if thats what you were referring to , i just made it this way . else i guess its just a program that inserts a record into a database.

Comment: Also,from what i have tried on , what i can conclude is that without the final ResultSet even if it is like 
ResultSet2 = stat.executeQuery("Select * from mytable) ;
while(rs2.next());
it doesnt update it. the new result set has to be generated of which i dont understand why .autocommit is set to true by default.

Comment: To start, `static Connection` is a very bad idea. It may lead to unforeseen problems.

Comment: DONE!@ZEKI : con.close() did it !

Comment: @BalusC : ohh..ok i will make sure i wont do that again :)Please can you tell me some more problems with it so that i keep those in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you ever CLOSE your statements, resultsets and connections? They should be, in a finally clause.

Answer (score 0):

The automatic commit doesn't occur until you have retrieved the result set, even on an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement. See: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

> the default is for a SQL statement to be committed when it is completed, not when it is executed. A statement is completed when all of its result sets and update counts have been retrieved.

Try sending a commit to the database via `con.commit()` right after you execute it if you are not interested in the update result.

Comment: the problem is i have other programs with such statement and executeUpdate() and they are working normal. this doesnt seem to work. does it work on your IDE?